# How to prevent dead code being optimized by JVM?

Tags: jvm, jpda

```
public class A
{
    public String getText()
    {
        Marker.start();
        ...
        ...
        Marker.end();
    }
}

public class Marker
{
    public static void start()
    {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis;
    }

    public static void end()
    {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis;
    }
}
```

I want to use JPDA (Java Platform Debugger Architecture) to detect the occurrence of Marker.start() and Marker.end() from external application. However I think the code may be optimized / eliminated away by JVM. How to prevent dead code being optimized by JVM?

Answer (score 0):

You could for example create a fake `int` variable somewhere in the class `Marker` and increment/decrement its value in the `start()` and `end()` methods. I don't think any optimizer could remove an instance field from a class even if the value is not used anywhere. After all, someone could always inject new agent code into the JVM and ask for the value. This means calls to `start()` and `stop()` shouldn't get optimized out, either.

Comment: I will let you know the result after I have done the experiment. I guess the optimizer would skip the execution of Marker.start() completely.